# About the prototype object and it's role in Javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-programming

I have only just started messing up with Javascript inheritance and can't get my hed round this one:

If I run this code:

```
function Foo(y) {
    this.y = y;
}

Foo.prototype.x = 1;

var Bar1 = new Foo(2);
var Bar2 = new Foo(3);
```

I expect to have the following "structure" in memory:
[image]
*I messed up in the graphic, Bar2 obviously has a value of "3" for its property "y"*

And happily enough, I can confirm that, by running this code:

```
console.log("Prototype - x: ", Foo.prototype.x, " y: ", Foo.prototype.y);
console.log("Bar1 - x: ", Bar1.x, " y: ", Bar1.y);
console.log("Bar2 - x: ", Bar2.x, " y: ", Bar2.y);
```

which prints:

```
Prototype - x: 1 y: undefined
Bar1 - x: 1 y: 2
Bar2 - x: 1 y: 3
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but what is happening there is that when I try to access the property x in the Bar1 and Bar2 objects, as those objects don't localy have a property called x, I'm getting that property from the next object in the prototype chain; i.e. the one whose reference they store in their "_ *proto* _" property.

Now is when I get lost, because if I after that code I alter the value of x like this:

```
Bar1.x = 10;
```

when I now run

```
console.log("Prototype - x: ", Foo.prototype.x, " y: ", Foo.prototype.y);
console.log("Bar1 - x: ", Bar1.x, " y: ", Bar1.y);
console.log("Bar2 - x: ", Bar2.x, " y: ", Bar2.y);
```

what I'am getting is

```
Prototype - x: 1 y: undefined
Bar1 - x: 10 y: 2
Bar2 - x: 1 y: 3
```

instead of what I would expect :

```
Prototype - x: 10 y: undefined
Bar1 - x: 10 y: 2
Bar2 - x: 10 y: 3
```

At that moment I could only explain that by assuming that each object was creating a copy of the Foo.prototype object, but if I run this

```
console.log(Object.is(Foo.prototype, Bar1.__proto__), Object.is(Bar1.__proto__, Bar2.__proto__));
```

I get `true true`, so both Bar1, Bar2 are accesing the same object.

Why is Bar1 then showing a different value for x if they are both getting it from the same object?

Comment: Why would you expect `Bar2` to get the value `10`, when it has only been placed on the `Bar1` object? Certainly we wouldn't want modifications to one object to affect *all* objects that share the same prototype, right? *"...I thought that each object was creating a copy of the Foo.prototype..."* There's no copy created when you edit. You merely edit the object.

Comment: ...to comprehend it, all you need to do is change your graphic to add `x 10` to the `Bar1` object, and that will reflect the entirety of what has taken place.

Comment: ...however, if you have an `Array` or an `Object` on the prototype, and you modify *that* object, naturally its changes will be observed from all objects that access it. `Foo.prototype.arr = []; Bar1.arr.push("foobar"); Bar2.arr.toString(); // "foobar"`

Comment: @cookiemonster Good point in the last comment!

I understand how it works now, cheers!

Comment: It's called shadowing assignment won't modify the prototype, only mutating will: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 It's same as passing object variables to a function. If the function does `passedObject={}` it doesn't affect the object passed to the function but if it does `passedObject.something=22` it mutates passedObject and will affect the object outside of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
Bar1.x = 10;
```

does not change the value of `x` in the prototype. Instead it creates a new property (`x`) for `Bar1` and assigns the value of `10` to it. `Bar1` therefore no longer inherits `x` from its prototype as it now has its own property `x`.

`Bar2` still does, which is why it still matches the prototype value.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simply:

> Assignment always creates or updates the property on the object itself.

An assignment never impacts the prototype chain, even if the property exists somewhere along the chain(*).

Only *reading* a property traverses along the prototype chain, stopping at the object that actually has that property.

If you are interested in the technicalities, have a look at the [`PutValue` definition in the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.2).

---

(*): However, if the property exists in the prototype chain, it may have an impact on the assignment. If the property exists and is *readonly* (not writable), the assignment doesn't
create a new property. Example:

```
> var obj = Object.create(Object.create({}, {x: {value: 10}}));
undefined
> obj.x
10
> obj.x = 100;
100
> obj.x
10
```

Comment: Thanks! Both your answer and pete's are great, I will accept his just because he posted it first.

Upvoted yours though :)

Comment: Also, it will not create a new property if the inherited one is a setter.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about how `Bar1` and `Bar2` are getting their values of `x`. But where it breaks down is when you assign `Bar1.x = 10`.

When trying to access `x`, it first starts at the object itself before crawling down the chain. Let's assume you try to access `Bar1.z`. The lookup would look something like this:

1. `Bar1.z`
2. `Bar1.prototype.z`
3. `Bar1.__proto__.z` i.e. `Foo.prototype`
4. `Object.prototype.z` (since all objects naturally inherit from `Object`
5. `z` not found, returns `undefined`

By assigning `Bar1.x`, you effectively shadow the value of `Bar1.__proto__.x` since it will appear first in the lookup.